# toLocaleString() not work on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add thousand separator for numbers as user is typing in. this is my code :

```
    $('.rls').on('input',function (e) {
       $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toLocaleString());
    });
```

It works correctly but when I enter dot character It doesnt add dot to input .what is the problem?

Comment: Is it a `type="number"` input element

Comment: Well, on each input you're overwriting the value of the input with its localized floating point representation. When the value is "55.", its representation will just be "55".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseFloat` function is always removing the "." so toLocalString will return the number without the "."

You could check if the last character is a "." and place it back. I also added a check for empty string because otherwise it will give a `NaN` if you delete all the numbers:

```js
$('.rls').on('input',function (e) {
   $this = $(this);
   const val = $this.val();
   if (val === "") {
       return;
   }
   let end = "";
   if (val.charAt(val.length-1) === ".") {
       end = ".";
   }
   $this.val(parseFloat($this.val()).toLocaleString() + end);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rls" />
```

Do bear in mind, some locales use "," as the decimal so I'm not sure if your code will break on them. Also, in my case, my locale uses "," as thousands separator and this breaks the parseFloat and removes everything after the "," if I write a number above 999.

I think it would be better to let the user input whatever numbers they want without changing the input box while they are writing in it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Learn to do it without jquery, what is in js core, and you will often find the solution.

```
document.querySelector(".rls")[0].oninput =  (function(e){
  e.value = +e.value.toLocaleString()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```js
document.querySelector("#number-input").oninput = (function(e) {
        var input = document.getElementById('number-input')
        input.name = input.value.replaceAll('.', '')
        if (input.value == "" || input.value == undefined || isNaN(parseInt(input.name)) == true) {
            input.value = 0
            input.name =  "0"
        } else {
            input.value = parseInt(input.name).toLocaleString()
        }        
    })
```

```html
<input type='text' id='number-input'></input>
```